# Function is bounded on plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, inequality

Let $f(x,y)=-\dfrac{2x^3y}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ for $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ and $f(0,0)=0.$ Prove that $f$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ we have: $$|f(x,y)|=\dfrac{2|x|^3|y|}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\leqslant \dfrac{2|x|^3|y|+2|x||y|^3}{(x^2+y^2)^2}=\dfrac{2|xy|(x^2+y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}=\dfrac{2|xy|}{x^2+y^2}\leqslant 1$$ The last inequality from AM-GM inequality. Thus $|f(x,y)|\leqslant 1$ for any $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 1):

In polar coordinates it's $-\frac{2r^4\cos^3\theta\sin\theta}{r^4}=-2\cos^3\theta\sin\theta$ which is bounded for all $(r,\theta)$ since $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$ are both bounded by $1$.